# Can i play games from my macbook who's been on my phone? Please help

Tags: iphone, icloud, macbook-pro, games

I'm playing Township on my iphone. 
I just found out you can play it on your macbook as well. 
Is it possible to be continue with the game on my computer without starting over? I have connected my apps from my iphone to iCloud. Is there any chance i can keep playing my game but on my macbook?

Comment: what is a från ?

Comment: @Buscar웃 "från" is Swedish for "from". Appearently nicole just reverted to her native language while typing :)